# Android release build - MissingDefaultResource "error"

Tags: android, cordova, apk, release, android-resources

As I prepare my Android/Cordova app for release I have just done my first release build `cordova build android --release`.  The build happens and Cordova obliges with the release apk in the `platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release` folder as expected.

However, as it goes about doing this it emits a series of "error" messages along the lines of

> The drawable "screen" in drawable-land-ldpi has no declaration in the base drawable folder or in a drawable-densitydpi folder; this can lead to crashes when the drawable is queried in a configuration that does not match this qualifier [MissingDefaultResource]

Further down it provides a somewhat reassuring qualification in the form

> Explanation for issues of type "MissingDefaultResource":
>      If a resource is only defined in folders with qualifiers like -land or -en,
>      and there is no default declaration in the base folder (layout or values
>      etc), then the app will crash if that resource is accessed on a device
>      where the device is in a configuration missing the given qualifier.
>
> As a special case, drawables do not have to be specified in the base
>      folder; if there is a match in a density folder (such as drawable-mdpi)
>      that image will be used and scaled. Note however that if you  only specify
>      a drawable in a folder like drawable-en-hdpi, the app will crash in
>      non-English locales.

I am providing my image resources in the `app/src/main/res/drawable-land-???dpi` folders.  I restrict my app to work in landscape mode only and I do not have any `app/src/main/res/drawable-port-???dpi` folders.  The default `/app/src/main/res/drawable` folder is present but is empty.

I am doing this to avoid lumbering the app with many Mb of never-to-used graphics.  I do not, and do not plan to, provide region/locale specific resources. The localization of UI strings used in my app are handled internally in my own way.

My question - given the above am I likely to run the risk of an "crash" as the error message proclaims initially prior to issuing the reassurance quoted above?

Comment: Did you find out the root of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

you can use tools:ignore="MissingDefaultResource" to ignore the issue

Comment: You add this to the top-level tag in the xml file, I presume?